# Prove function is continuous at x = 0.5 and discontinuous at every other point

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given $f = x ,  x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f =1 -  x ,  x \notin \mathbb{Q}$

I am trying to see this using sequence approach but couldnot get to it

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

- What is $$|f(0.5)-f(x)|$$ equal to if $x\in\mathbb Q$?
- What is $$|f(0.5)-f(x)|$$ equal to if $x\notin\mathbb Q$?

Comment: I see this  but I need rigorous proof for continuity

Comment: @J.Deff Well, what I wrote is a hint. You can use it to prove continuity via $\epsilon-\delta$, for example.

Comment: how to prove, I cant do

Comment: @J.Deff I can't do it in a minute either.